# How to get scroll offset in mobile Safari in standalone (web-app) mode?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

In Mobile Safari on iOS 6 (and all other major browsers), using `window.pageYOffset` gives me what I'm looking for. But, when I use the standalone mode (add bookmark to home screen to run web-app in full-screen) the `window.pageYOffset` always returns 0! How can I get the vertical scroll offset in this situation?